# Wrap some components in a custom div in Angular Schema Form

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angular-schema-form, custom-formatting

How can I wrap some elements in a `div` like tabs, but in a `div` with custom classes?

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have used type 'section' and it solved all my problems.